# What happens when i copy pthread_rwlock_t?

Tags: c++, c

```
pthread_rwlock t1;
pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&t1);

pthread_rwlock t2 = t1;
```

what happend?
is t2 locked or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing special happens. `pthread_rwlock_t` (not `pthread_rwlock`, AFAIK) is an opaque C struct. Copying the variable simply copies the struct, byte for byte.

At the Pthreads level, copying a `pthread_rwlock_t` results in undefined behaviour. Don't do it.

Comment: sorry, i mean: after
t2 = t1, is t2 locked or not?

Comment: i make a test, t2 is not locked, it seems different your answer: copy byte by byte.

Comment: @Raymond: Add your first comment to your question, since it clarifies things quite a bit. What happens at the Pthreads level when you copy these data types is undefined; you should not copy these structs. But there is no question: the struct is copied byte by byte.

Answer (score 0):

A new copy is created. The below example may clear things

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
char a[8];
}example;
int main()
{
example s1, s2;
strcpy(s1.a,"Hi");
s2=s1;
printf("%s %s \n",s1.a,s2.a);
strcpy(s2.a,"There");
printf("%s %s \n",s1.a,s2.a);
return 0;
}
```

This will output:

```
Hi Hi
Hi There
```